# Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

The code is executing what it is supposed to do but I'm getting 2 errors in the console: "Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined". Confused as to why it's throwing errors since the two variables are defined as global variables. Am I missing something? (Using TextureLoader() since ImageUtils.loadTexture() has been deprecated).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Three.js</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r80/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>

        //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        var scene, camera, renderer, cameraControl, earthMesh, cloudMesh;

        function init(){

            //scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor('#000', 1.0);
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

            //camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.x = 35;
            camera.position.y = 36;
            camera.position.z = 33;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            //earth mesh
            var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 60, 60);
            var sphereMaterial;
            var sphereMaterialLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            sphereMaterialLoader.load(
                'images/earth.jpg',
                function(earthImage){
                    sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        map: earthImage
                    });
                    earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
                    earthMesh.name = 'earth';
                    scene.add(earthMesh);
                    render();   
                }
            );

            //cloud mesh
            var cloudGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphereGeometry.parameters.radius * 1.02, 
                sphereGeometry.parameters.widthSegments, sphereGeometry.parameters.heightSegments);
            var cloudMaterial;
            var cloudMaterialLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            cloudMaterialLoader.load(
                'images/clouds.png',
                function(cloudImage){
                    cloudMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        map: cloudImage
                    });
                    cloudMaterial.transparent = true;
                    cloudMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeometry, cloudMaterial);
                    cloudMesh.name = 'cloud';
                    scene.add(cloudMesh);
                    render();
                }
            );

            //camera control
            cameraControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            render();
        }

        function render(){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            earthMesh.rotation.y += -0.001;
            cloudMesh.rotation.y += 0.0005;
            cameraControl.update();
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }

        //initialize scene/render
        window.onload = init;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `earthMesh` is being initialized asynchronously in your cloudMaterialLoader.load() function -- you need to be careful as when you first call render() `earthMesh` may not be yet loaded, in which case it will still be undefined.

A few ways to work with this would be to not call render() until the earthMesh is loaded, or to check if earthMesh has been loaded in the render() call, or anything up to your imagination.

Comment: Is there a way to check if all the textures have been loaded before calling the render function for the first time?